# Can't boot Ubuntu 18.04 -- missing 'lowerdir' -- failed to connect to lvmetad

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, kernel

I seem to have the same problem as [Robin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068588/boot-problem-after-update-missing-lowerdir/1156527#1156527), and I have indeed had an nvidia driver installed.  The last things I did were "apt get update" and "apt get upgrade".  I'm able to login to recovery mode (as described [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/boot-recovery-mode-ubuntu/)), but can't perform either step proposed by Robin because I don't seem to have internet access in recovery mode (I get "Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com').  I was trying to reinstall the driver using the instructions [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/).

I have the following kernel options (each with recovery mode):

- 4.15.0-55-generic
- 4.15.0-54-generic
- 4.15.0-52-generic

but none works (they give the various error messages cited by Robin).

I'm also not able to find my downloaded driver or the instructions I used to install it since I can't access my home directory in recovery mode.  There is a message in a README.txt file  "THIS DIRECTORY HAS BEEN UNMOUNTED TO PROTECT YOUR DATA." and directing me to run ecryptfs-mount-private from the command line.  I am able to run that without error after su-ing into my user (as recommended [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1642790)) but my home folder is still not available.

I also saw [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122512/nvidia-modules-are-missing-after-each-kernel-upgrade-in-18-04), but don't have dkms installed either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I did have internet access but DNS was somehow misconfigured.  I was able to reconfigure it as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368435/how-do-i-fix-dns-resolving-which-doesnt-work-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10-s) with

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

I was then able to follow the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105090/cant-change-to-proprietary-display-driver-ubuntu-18-04) for reinstalling nvidia drivers.

My home directory was available from a user login.